# Преобразование времени, полученного с сервера

Tags: json, swift, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, форматирование

Работаю с API Вконтакте. Пытаюсь преобразовать время с помощью TimeFormatter. С сервера я получаю время, с помощью SwiftyJSON, в формате Int64. Когда я пытаюсь применить форматер к времени, полученного с сервера, у меня на симуляторе показывается, что оно составляет 25 секунд, хотя в реальности это не так. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы отображалось реальное время? Код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
    '''
    class TimeFormatter{

```
    private var seconds = TimeInterval()
    //Метод, преобразующий время в нужный формат
    private func timeFormatter (_ : TimeInterval) -> DateComponentsFormatter{
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        // Длительность будет отображаться как 1:00:00
        if seconds > 59.59{
            formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        }

        else{
            formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
        }

        formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad


        return formatter
    }

    //Метод, передающий информацию о длительности записи в приложение
    func convertTimeToString(_ number: Int64?) -> String?{



        if let unwrappedNumber = number{

            seconds = TimeInterval(integerLiteral: unwrappedNumber)

            print(seconds)
        }

        let formatter = timeFormatter(seconds)
        let timeString = formatter.string(from: seconds)

        return timeString


    }







}
''' 
//Метод, в котором преобразуется время, полученное с сервера
func setTime(_ : Int64?) -> String? {
        let count = self.getPostsCount()
        for counter in 0...count-1{
        let post = self.getPost(for: counter)
            if let attachments = post.attachments{
                for attachment in attachments{
                    end64 = attachment.audio!.duration

                    if let audioTime = end64{

                        end = TimeInterval(integerLiteral: audioTime)

                        time = TimeFormatter().convertTimeToString(audioTime)
                       }
                    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: MusicTableViewCell.self, selector: #selector(countSeconds(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

                    if end == 0.0{
                        timer.invalidate()
                    }
                }
            }


        }
       return time
    }
    '''
   Фото полученных результатов и реального времени во ВКонтакте.
[![введите сюда код][1]][1]
```

Comment: Приведите пример получаемого с сервера времени и результата на выходе

Comment: Длительность записи - 1:43:00. Когда я делаю запрос к серверу, мне приходит код 25. Соответственно, длительность записи отображается как 00:25

Comment: Значит дело не в неверном форматировании, а в получаемом ответе, форматирование тут не при чем

Comment: Мне кажется, что дело все-таки в форматировании, ибо и код 25, и 1:43:00 одно и то же. Ведь мне не писали сообщений о том, что авторизация не удалась или что не удалось получить время. Попробую получить данные, поставив тип с другим количеством бит. Если не получится, тогда будем обсуждать дальше

Comment: Тогда как я понимаю дело в строке `time = TimeFormatter().convertTimeToString(audioTime)`, то бишь `audioTime` у вас имеет верное значение, а `time` получается неверным?

Comment: Установка типа с меньшим количеством бит и перевод его в TimeInterval не удались

Comment: Да, получается так.

Comment: Биты тут не при чем, если `audioTime` приходит верный, то покажите его значение, а также значение `time` на выходе

Comment: Дайте минимальный пример со значениями, который поможет воспроизвести проблему

Comment: По сути это будет заодно чем-то  вроде модульного теста (можно даже добавить `assert`)

Comment: Знаете, мне кажется, ошибка может заключаться в том, что я ещё не запросил аудиозаписи у группы. Я думал сначала написать приложение, а потом запросить у группы согласия на его распространение. Поэтому мне может быть доступен  только отрывок аудиозаписи. Если я попрошу доступ к одной записи, то будут ли мне доступны остальные?

Comment: насчет API вконтакте я ничего сказать не могу (и это уже другой вопрос), вопрос у вас заключался в правильности форматирования, и судя по всему проблема не в нем, что и требовалось доказать

Comment: Ну что ж, в любом случае, дискуссия была полезной. Спасибо Вам

Comment: @schmidt9 ,Здравствуйте! Не могли бы Вы посмотреть задачу на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091435/Преобразование-времени-полученного-с-сервера ?

Comment: дали ссылку на этот же вопрос

Comment: Прошу прощения. Вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1094670/Не-удается-включить-таймер