# Не удается включить таймер

Tags: swift, mvp, таймер

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку включался таймер, отсчитывал секунды, а после остановки, при повторном воспроизведении, начинал отсчет с той секунды, на которой остановился при нажатии на паузу. Но сейчас у меня никаких изменений со временем не происходит, хотя изображение на кнопке меняется. Код:

```
//MusicViewController

private var second64: Int64?

private var second = TimeInterval()

private var time: String?

//В этом методе мы считаем секунды
    @objc private func countSeconds( _ : TimeInterval) -> TimeInterval{

        if second > 0.0{

           second -= 1.0

            second64 = Int64(second)
            time = TimeFormatter().convertTimeToString(second64)

        }



        return second
    }



  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

//Воспроизводим длительность аудиозаписи в основном потоке
           second64 = audio.duration
                    time = TimeFormatter().convertTimeToString(second64)



                    var timer = Timer()

                    if button.title(for: .normal) == "▶️"{
                        if button.isSelected{

                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0){

                                timer = self.setTimer()



                                cell.durationLabel.text = self.time

                            }

                        }

                        else if button.title(for: .selected) == "⏸" {

                            if button.isSelected{
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0){
                                timer.invalidate()

                                cell.durationLabel.text = self.time
                            }
                            }
                    }
                    }
                }

                    else{
                    cell.singerLabel.text! = ""
                    cell.titleLabel.text! = ""
                }
}
//Метод в протоколе для взаимодействия с презентером.
func setTimer () -> Timer{

      let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(countSeconds(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    print(second)
      return timer
  }
}


class TimeFormatter{

private var seconds = TimeInterval()
//Метод, преобразующий время в нужный формат
private func timeFormatter (_ : TimeInterval) -> DateComponentsFormatter{
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    // Длительность будет отображаться как 1:00:00
    if seconds > 59.59{
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    }

    else{
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    }

    formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad


    return formatter
}

//Метод, передающий информацию о длительности записи в приложение
func convertTimeToString(_ number: Int64?) -> String?{



    if let unwrappedNumber = number{

        seconds = TimeInterval(integerLiteral: unwrappedNumber)

        print(seconds)
    }

    let formatter = timeFormatter(seconds)
    let timeString = formatter.string(from: seconds)

    return timeString


}

}
```

---

UPD.
Теперь мой код выглядит так:
//MusicViewController

private var index = Int()

```
private var posts: [Post] = []

private var timer: Timer?

private var playingCell: MusicTableViewCell?{

    let count = store!.getPostsCount()

    for i in 0...count-1{

        index = i

        let post = store!.getPost(for: index)

        posts.append(post)
    }

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)

    return tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MusicTableViewCell
```

private func reset(){

```
    guard let cell = playingCell, let button = cell.playButton, let post = store?.getPost(for: index), let attachments = post.attachments, let audio = attachments[index].audio else {return}

    button.isSelected = false

    second64 = audio.duration

    cell.second = cell.makeTimeIntervalFromInt(second64)

}
```

//Метод останавливает музыку на текущем моменте
    private func pauseMusic() {

```
    guard let cell = playingCell, let playbutton = cell.playButton else {return}

    playbutton.isSelected = false

    timer?.invalidate()
```

}

}
private var second64: Int64?
//private let second = TimeInterval(integerLiteral: second64!)

extension MusicViewController: UITableViewDataSource, MusicTableViewCellDelegate{

```
func musicShouldStartPlaying(_ cell: MusicTableViewCell) {

    if cell !== playingCell{

        musicShouldStopPlaying(cell)

    }

    cell.playButton.isSelected = true

    timer = cell.setTimer()

}

func musicShouldStopPlaying(_ cell: MusicTableViewCell) {

    if cell.second == 0.0 || cell !== playingCell{

        cell.playButton.isSelected = false

        pauseMusic()

        reset()

    }

    else{
        cell.playButton.isSelected = false

        pauseMusic()

    }

    cell.playButton.isSelected = false

    pauseMusic()

}
```

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let button = cell.playButton!

```
    button.actions(forTarget: button, forControlEvent: .touchUpInside)
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.index = indexPath.row
    cell.second = cell.makeTimeIntervalFromInt(second64)
}
//MusicTableViewCell
 var second64: Int64?
var index: Int!
```

var second = TimeInterval()

```
private var time: String?

weak var delegate: MusicTableViewCellDelegate?
func makeTimeIntervalFromInt( _ : Int64?) -> TimeInterval{
    if let currentSecond = second64{
    second = TimeInterval(integerLiteral: currentSecond)
    }
    return second
}
```

//Протокол взаимодействия View с презентером
protocol ViewProto: class {

```
//Метод, вызывающий презентер во View
func setPresenter(_ presenter: PresenterProto)

//Метод, обновляющий посты
func updateData()
```

// func reset()

}

//Протокол взаимодействия презентера с View
protocol PresenterProto: class {

```
// Метод, вызывающий View в презентере
func viewLoaded(with view: ViewProto)

//Метод, позволяющий узнать количество постов в массиве
func getPostsCount() -> Int

//Показывает содержание конкретного поста
func getPost(for index: Int) -> Post
```

}

protocol MusicTableViewCellDelegate: class{
    func musicShouldStartPlaying(_ cell: MusicTableViewCell)

```
func musicShouldStopPlaying(_ cell: MusicTableViewCell)

//func reset(_ cell: MusicTableViewCell)
```

}

'''

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сделайте пример, который можно запустить, разделите логику запуска таймера и отсчета времени, сейчас у вас какие-то непонятные обрывки кода здесь

Comment: Забыл метод для таймера сюда включить)

Comment: Я пробовал также вызывать setTimer во ViewController с использованием еще нескольких if else блоков и DispatchQueue, но это не помогло

Comment: Научитесь пожалуйста нормально форматировать код, это несложно, а читать легче будет. Далее я уже писал - оставьте _только_ логику таймера, уберите все, что связано с проигрыванием, сократите код до самого минимума, добейтесь работоспособности и потом уже добавляйте функционал, вы так и не указали что и где конкретно не работает, многие вещи элементарно вычисляются с помощью отладчика и поэтапного отслеживания с помощью точек останова или логирования

Comment: @schmidt9, проблема с отображением секунд в Label. Я добавил while и if циклы в countSeconds, чтобы посмотреть, отобразится ли время в ячейке, если указать, что 0 тоже можно отобразить. Ячейка по-прежнему пуста

Comment: @schmidt9, но я упорядочил массив постов в модели при помощи двух итераций по нему

Comment: не, так мы далеко не уедем, предлагаю вам сделать отдельный тестовый проект (оставив только код таймера) и залить его куда-то, я гляну

Comment: @schmidt9, добавил проект на Github: https://github.com/IvanNextToJunior/TimerForMVP. При переписывании проекта у меня возник ряд проблем, от неработавшей кнопки до неупорядоченных постов и выкладывания проекта, поэтому вышло так долго. Я сделал репозиторий приватным. Единственная проблема, которая добавилась при создании отдельного проекта - Label, в которое передается время, не появляется вообще, куда я ее не перетаскиваю и как ни сужаю размеры ячейки, хотя outlet есть

Comment: сделайте репозиторий публичным либо дайте какие либо свои контакты, спишемся и Вы сможете добавить меня в список контрибьюторов проекта

Comment: @schmidt9, вроде добавил. Проверьте

Comment: Да увидел гляну попозже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример работы с возобновляемым таймером.

**Дополнение**

<strike>Вам нужно обновлять время в методе `countSeconds` как показано ниже</strike>

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var durationLabel: UILabel!

    private var seconds = TimeInterval()

    private var timeString = ""

    private var timer: Timer?

    private var isPlaying = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        seconds = 100
    }

    @IBAction func playButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        togglePlayback()

        playButton.setTitle(isPlaying ? "Stop" : "Play", for: .normal)
    }

    @objc private func countSeconds(_ sender: Timer) {
        if seconds > 0.0 {
            seconds -= 1.0
            timeString = TimeFormatter.convertTimeToString(seconds)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.durationLabel.text = self.timeString
            }
        }
    }

    func togglePlayback() {
        isPlaying = !isPlaying

        if isPlaying {
            startTimer()
        } else {
            stopTimer()
        }
    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
            timeInterval: 1.0,
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(countSeconds(_ :)),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

}
```

**Дополнение 2**

Задача показалась мне интересной, я полностью переписал реализацию автора вопроса и сделал тестовый проект с логикой переключения записей в списке ([github](https://github.com/schmidt9/TimerTest))

Первоначально я перенес логику переключения и отслеживания времени в ячейки, однако это оказалось неверным решением из-за повторного использования ячеек при прокрутке и соответственно остановки таймера, работающего в выбранной ячейке, поэтому я сделал общий таймер во вью контроллере, и здесь столкнулся с тем, что обычный `Timer` тоже останавливается при прокрутке, так как запускается в основном цикле событий (main loop).

Поэтому я использовал реализацию фонового таймера [отсюда](https://medium.com/over-engineering/a-background-repeating-timer-in-swift-412cecfd2ef9)

*Замечания:*

- иногда при возобновлении таймера в начале быстро проскакивает первая секунда
- неоптимальный вариант получения текущей ячейки для обновления времени в ней при большом списке

Класс ячейки содержит кнопку переключения и лейбл для вывода времени, внутри управляет переключением кнопки и делегирует события переключения во вью контроллер

```
class RecordDurationFormatter : DateComponentsFormatter {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        unitsStyle = .positional
        zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    }

    /// Метод, преобразующий время в нужный формат
    func format(_ seconds: TimeInterval) -> String? {

        // Длительность будет отображаться как 1:00:00
        if seconds > 59.59 {
            allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        } else {
            allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
        }

        return string(from: seconds)
    }
}


protocol RecordTableViewCellDelegate : class {

    func recordTableViewCellShouldStartPlaying(_ cell: RecordTableViewCell)
    func recordTableViewCellShouldPausePlaying(_ cell: RecordTableViewCell)

}

class RecordTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!

    private let stoppedTitle = "▶️"
    private let playingTitle = "⏸"

    let formatter = RecordDurationFormatter()

    private var timer: Timer?

    var recordIndex: Int!

    var isPlaying: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            togglePlayButtonTitle(playing: isPlaying)
        }
    }

    var seconds: TimeInterval = 0 {
        didSet {
            updateTimeLabelText()
        }
    }

    weak var delegate: RecordTableViewCellDelegate?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        togglePlayButtonTitle(playing: false)
    }

    // MARK: UI Update

    private func togglePlayButtonTitle(playing: Bool) {
        playButton.setTitle(playing ? playingTitle : stoppedTitle, for: .normal)
    }

    func updateTimeLabelText() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.timeLabel.text = self.formatter.format(self.seconds)
        }
    }

    // MARK: UI Events

    @IBAction func playButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        isPlaying = !isPlaying

        if isPlaying {
            delegate?.recordTableViewCellShouldStartPlaying(self)
        } else {
            delegate?.recordTableViewCellShouldPausePlaying(self)
        }
    }

}
```

Вью контроллер содержит таблицу, управляет таймером и переключением между записями

```
class Record {

    var isPlaying = false
    var duration: TimeInterval = 100
    lazy var currentSeconds = duration

    func reset() {
        isPlaying = false
        currentSeconds = duration
    }

    func countDown() -> TimeInterval {
        if currentSeconds > 0 {
            currentSeconds -= 1.0
        }

        return currentSeconds
    }

}

class RecordsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    private var seconds = TimeInterval()

    /// Using background timer because common Timer is getting suspended
    /// on table view scroll (because of schedule on main loop)
    private var timer = RepeatingTimer(timeInterval: 1)

    private var records: [Record] = []

    private var playingRecord: Record?

    // TODO: maybe optimize because is gets called by timer via playingCell every second
    private var playingRecordIndex: Int? {
        records.firstIndex { $0 === playingRecord }
    }

    private var playingCell: RecordTableViewCell? {
        guard let index = playingRecordIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        return tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RecordTableViewCell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nibName = String(NSStringFromClass(RecordTableViewCell.self).split(separator: ".").last!)
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        for _ in 0..<100 {
            records.append(Record())
        }
    }

    // MARK: Playback

    /// Resume or start record
    func startRecord(with index: Int) {
        let record = records[index]
        record.isPlaying = true
        playingRecord = record

        startTimer()
    }

    func stopPlayingNowRecord() {
        guard let record = playingRecord, let cell = playingCell else {
            return
        }

        record.reset()

        cell.seconds = record.duration
        cell.isPlaying = false

        stopTimer()
    }

    func pausePlayingNowRecord() {
        guard let record = playingRecord else {
            return
        }

        record.isPlaying = false

        stopTimer()
    }

    // MARK: Timer

    @objc private func countSeconds() {
        guard let record = self.playingRecord else {
            return
        }

        seconds = record.countDown()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let cell = self.playingCell else {
                return
            }

            cell.seconds = self.seconds
        }
    }

    private func startTimer() {

        if timer.eventHandler == nil {
            timer.eventHandler = {
                self.countSeconds()
            }
        }

        timer.resume()
    }

    private func stopTimer() {
        timer.suspend()
    }

}

extension RecordsViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        records.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! RecordTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.recordIndex = indexPath.row

        let record = records[indexPath.row]
        cell.seconds = record.currentSeconds
        cell.isPlaying = record.isPlaying

        return cell
    }

}

extension RecordsViewController : RecordTableViewCellDelegate {

    func recordTableViewCellShouldStartPlaying(_ cell: RecordTableViewCell) {
        if cell !== playingCell {
            // stop previous record if any
            stopPlayingNowRecord()
        }

        startRecord(with: cell.recordIndex)
    }

    func recordTableViewCellShouldPausePlaying(_ cell: RecordTableViewCell) {
        pausePlayingNowRecord()
    }

}
```

Comment: Добавил еще кода, чтобы была лучше понятна проблема. Она находится либо в методе setTimer, либо при преобразовании времени в ячейке. Но в чем она заключается - непонятно

Comment: @ИванМаслов для начала попробуйте удалить из методов не относящийся к делу код, примерно как в моем ответе, можете даже в мой пример добавлять постепенно свою логику и проверять, либо оставьте у себя только логику включения / выключения таймера (если дело действительно в этом), тогда разобраться будет легче и вам, и тому, кто вам захочет помочь

Comment: Я попробовал поставить код countSeconds и код после инициализации переменной timer на основной поток, в результате timeLabel стала пустой

Comment: @ИванМаслов см дополнение

Comment: я не профессиональный разработчик, но мне Ваше решение нравится. Единственное, что я хотел бы Вас попросить, - не могли бы Вы подстроить решение под использование с протоколами tableViewDataSource и tableViewDelegate? Самому сообразить, как это сделать, у меня пока не получается, но я добавил ещё один DispatchQueue.main и durationLabel.text = self.time. Время вновь появилось, но по-прежнему количество секунд не меняется.

Comment: @ИванМаслов вам нужно мой код поместить в кастомный класс ячейки таблицы, а не выполнять во  вью контроллере

Comment: спасибо. Думаю, должно сработать

Comment: @ИванМаслов а во вью контроллере реализовать логику переключения между треками

Comment: ошибка пока не исчезла. Я переместил методы по работе со временем в ячейку, а вызывать стал в контроллере, но Label снова пуста.

Comment: я сделал таймер константой, чтобы не было возможности ему присвоить какой-то другой таймер, кроме описанного в методе setTimer, убрал TimeFormatter во ViewController, обновил Xcode и перезапустил симулятор, но timeLabel все еще пуста

Comment: @ИванМаслов я набросал новый в целом рабочий вариант, если получится, то опубликую его

Comment: @ИванМаслов я обновил ответ

Comment: я нашел способ, как реализовать вариант включения таймера в ячейке. По-моему, это должно занять меньше кода. Но у меня не получается его реализовать. Не могли бы Вы мне помочь? Насколько мне известно, для его реализации нужно использовать indexpathsforvisiblerows: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160628/countdown-timer-in-every-table-cell. Я пробовал пройтись по visibleCells и path и прокатить каждую ячейку как MusicTableViewCell, но это не помогло

Comment: @ИванМаслов в этом ответе есть хорошая идея насчет поиска ячейки среди видимых (чтобы не искать среди всех), вместе с тем я написал, что таймеры в ячейках мне не удалось сделать, так как сами ячейки используются повторно

Comment: Кроме того, единый таймер поможет вам впоследствии например сделать панель с текущим проигрываемым треком вверху или внизу плейлиста

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Comment: я попробовал, опираясь на Ваше решение, написать программу для таймера в MVP. Но мой код что-то не работает. Не могли бы Вы мне помочь разобраться, в чем проблема, потому что я уверен, что программа может работать и с обычным таймером. Примером тому служит https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160628/countdown-timer-in-every-table-cell. Но как это сделать для повторно использующихся ячеек -  пока не ясно.

Comment: @ИванМаслов Я вам рекомендую взять мой проект и добавлять свой код, все время проверяя работоспособность, по указанной Вами ссылке нет никаких доказательств работоспособности, почему обычный таймер тут не подойдет, я уже писал - он будет останавливаться при прокрутке и обновлении интерфейса

Comment: @ИванМаслов и это вы ещё не добрались до работы приложения в фоне, где вообще никакие таймеры работать не будут и нужно будет делать возобновление отсчета вручную

Comment: Я безусловно благодарен за Ваш вклад в решение моего вопроса и стараюсь выполнить Ваши рекомендации. Но у меня проблема именно с модификацией Вашего кода под свой проект и, если Вас не затруднит, хотел бы получить Вашу консультацию по нему

Comment: @ИванМаслов тогда обновите свой вопрос, а то пока непонятно что у вас не получается

Comment: обновление кода готово.